# Help with MySQL statement

Tags: sql, mysql

I have written the following SQL statement in MySQL :

```
USE my_database;
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_column IN (1, 2, 3);
```

This returns a set of rows that have a column value which is a key into a row of another table (call it `some_other_table`).

```
a b c d <--this is the column with the key
      1
      2
      3
```

I want to say, look up all of the rows in another table with value 1, and do something (null out some column)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: With "do something" you mean "update" ?

Comment: Yes - I mean update.  Why is this being down voted?  I hope the person who down voted has the courtesy to give a reason so I learn something.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your description. Can you make up some names for "a column", "another table", "some column", etc.? As is it sounds like you just need `UPDATE some_other_table SET some_column=NULL WHERE d=1` which can't be right.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the advice.  I'll update the example shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the multiple-table `UPDATE` syntax:

```
UPDATE some_other_table
JOIN   some_table ON (some_table.some_key = some_other_table.id)
SET    some_other_table.some_field = NULL
WHERE  some_table.some_column IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (id int, some_column int, some_key int);
CREATE TABLE some_other_table (id int, some_field int);

INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (2, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (3, 3, 3);
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (4, 4, 4);
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (5, 5, 5);

INSERT INTO some_other_table VALUES (1, 10);
INSERT INTO some_other_table VALUES (2, 20);
INSERT INTO some_other_table VALUES (3, 30);
INSERT INTO some_other_table VALUES (4, 40);
```

Before:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table;
+------+-------------+----------+
| id   | some_column | some_key |
+------+-------------+----------+
|    1 |           1 |        1 |
|    2 |           2 |        2 |
|    3 |           3 |        3 |
|    4 |           4 |        4 |
|    5 |           5 |        5 |
+------+-------------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM some_other_table;
+------+------------+
| id   | some_field |
+------+------------+
|    1 |         10 |
|    2 |         20 |
|    3 |         30 |
|    4 |         40 |
+------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

After:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table;
+------+-------------+----------+
| id   | some_column | some_key |
+------+-------------+----------+
|    1 |           1 |        1 |
|    2 |           2 |        2 |
|    3 |           3 |        3 |
|    4 |           4 |        4 |
|    5 |           5 |        5 |
+------+-------------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM some_other_table;
+------+------------+
| id   | some_field |
+------+------------+
|    1 |       NULL |
|    2 |       NULL |
|    3 |       NULL |
|    4 |         40 |
+------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

**UPDATE:** Further to comments below.

Another example:

```
CREATE TABLE amir_effective_reference (class int, inst int, rln int, rclass int, rinst int, chg int, typ int);
CREATE TABLE amir_effective_change (chg int, txn int, rltn int, entry int, effective int);

INSERT INTO amir_effective_reference VALUES (1, 100, 1, 50, 20, 10, 5000);
INSERT INTO amir_effective_change VALUES (10, 100, 100, 500, 200);
```

Result:

```
UPDATE amir_effective_change 
JOIN   amir_effective_reference ON (amir_effective_reference.chg = amir_effective_change.chg) 
SET    amir_effective_change.effective = NULL 
WHERE  amir_effective_change.rltn IN (100);

SELECT * FROM amir_effective_change;
+------+------+------+-------+-----------+
| chg  | txn  | rltn | entry | effective |
+------+------+------+-------+-----------+
|   10 |  100 |  100 |   500 |      NULL |
+------+------+------+-------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I'm going to play around with this and provide and update shortly Daniel.  Thanks for the response.  BTW, I'm very new to SQL.

Comment: When I run this I get :

(0 row(s) affected)
Execution Time : 00:00:01:794
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:01:794

I'm assuming this means I did something wrong.

Comment: Do I need to say use this_db first?

Comment: @Amir: If `SELECT * FROM your_table` works, then you are already using the correct database. No need to `use this_db`. Are your tables similar to ones I created in the example of my answer? As you can see, it worked in my example. Or were you intending something different?

Comment: Daniel, I'm confused as to why you only have 1 row thats been nulled out if you had a list of 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: @Amir: Changed the data in my example. In the previous example, all rows in `some_table` had `some_key` = `1`. That is why only 1 row in `some_other_table` matched. You may find the new example clearer.

Comment: I run:
UPDATE amir_effective_change
JOIN   amir_effective_reference ON (amir_effective_reference.chg = amir_effective_change.chg)
SET    amir_effective_change.effective = NULL
WHERE  amir_effective_reference.rltn IN (100);

and my table looks like:
amir_effective_reference
class inst rln rclass rinst chg typ
1     100  1   50     20    10  5000

amir_effective_reference
chg  txn   rltn entry effective
10   100   100  500   200

Before and after is the same.

Comment: Shoot the comments make it looks really ugly.

Comment: I think you need to change the last bit to `WHERE  amir_effective_change.rltn IN (100);` instead of `amir_effective_reference.rltn` ?

Comment: amir_effective_reference.rltn is the starting table I'm looking at, so it should be correct, no?

Comment: @Amir: If `rltn` is a field of the `amir_effective_change` table, you have to use `amir_effective_change.rltn`. Otherwise, it's `amir_effective_reference.rltn` as in your previous comment :)

Comment: SELECT * FROM effective_change WHERE chg IN (SELECT chg FROM effective_reference WHERE rltn=7140);

returns the set of entries I'm interested in setting the values of column effective to NULL.  I just don't know how to set that column to NULL.

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM effective_change JOIN effective_reference ON (effective_reference.chg = effective_change.chg) WHERE rltn=7140;` return the same set of rows?

Comment: If yes, try `UPDATE effective_change JOIN effective_reference ON (effective_reference.chg = effective_change.chg) SET effective_change.effective = NULL WHERE rltn=7140;`

Comment: I'm gonna try that in a few minutes, I had to reload the database after I blew it up.

Comment: Yes Daniel that does return the right set of rows.  I'm curious why your UPDATE command sequence didn't work for me though?  It worked in the example, but not in the actual case.

Comment: What I want is this:
In table effective reference, if the column value is 7140, 210, x, y, get me that set.  For that set, use the chg as a key into the table effective_change and NULL out the column called effective

Comment: Do you get an error when you try `UPDATE effective_change JOIN effective_reference ON (effective_reference.chg = effective_change.chg) SET effective_change.effective = NULL WHERE rltn=7140;` or does it simply not make any change?

Comment: That actually works.  I'm curious as to what is the difference between this and the commands you gave me in the answer.